# sql syntax error while using top query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the top query for my table but facing the error

> You have an error in your sql syntax, chekck the manual that
>   corresponds to your mysql server version for the right sytntax to use
>   near '4 * from sitemain order by siteid desc limit 0,30' at line 1

here is the code which i used

```
SELECT top 4 *
FROM sitemain
ORDER BY siteid DESC
```

Comment: MySQL does not have `TOP`, it's SQL Server's way of doing `LIMIT`. Since it seems you have a `LIMIT 0,30` in your query too, what are you _really_ trying to achieve with adding `TOP`?

Comment: i amm just trying to mantain my "siteid" in descending order and then i want to select the first 4 rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing MySQL and TSQL syntax together. The query obviously is MySQL (from the error message). What you want is

```
SELECT * FROM sitemain ORDER BY siteid DESC LIMIT 0,4
```

Answer (score 3):

What you loking for is actually `LIMIT` Clause,

> The **LIMIT** clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

Documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

```
SELECT *
FROM sitemain
ORDER BY siteid DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM sitemain
ORDER BY siteid DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL you need to use the `LIMIT` command as explained [here](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm):

*Limit is used to limit your MySQL query results to those that fall within a specified range. You can use it to show the **first X number of results**, or to show a range from X - Y results. It is phrased as Limit X, Y and included at the end of your query. X is the starting point (remember the first record is 0) and Y is the duration (how many records to display).*

```
SELECT *
FROM sitemain
ORDER BY siteid DESC
LIMIT 4
```